# Printing (Canon Maxify MB2750) only prints the first page of documents

Tags: printing

My Ubuntu 21.10 used to work fine with my Canon Maxify MB2750 Printer, but since recently, whenever I try to print multiple-page documents, it only prints the first page, and then stops as if printing was complete.

I tried to change drivers, remove and reinstall the printer, everything stays the same. Printer works perfectly fine with Windows or from Android.

Does anyone have an idea of the problem involved, please ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Look at `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u cups`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, @waltinator

Answer (score 1):

Editing `/etc/cups/ppd/PRINTER_NAME.ppd` (replace your printer name) will work.

Find:

```
cupsManualCopies: true
```

Change `true` to capital letter T `True`:

```
cupsManualCopies: True
```

Comment: Same thing is true for other Canon printers. In my case it worked in the same way with the MB5450